# Converting Schengen visa to other visa type in Germany for extended stay as a specialist?

Tags: schengen-visas

I'm a software engineer attending a congress in Germany in July 2024 with a short-stay Schengen visa (up to 90 days). My nationality is Iranian.

1. Can I convert my Schengen visa to a work permit visa if I can get a job offer when I'm in Germany with that Schengen visa?
2. Can I convert my Schengen visa to a job seeker visa or any other kind of visa that lets me stay for 6 months or more to find a job in Germany or other Schengen countries when I'm there?

I don't have any financial problems and I have more than 5 years of provable work experience. I also have a Bachelor's degree in Computer Engineering.

Comment: No. If you enter Germany with a Schengen Visa or through the visa-free agreement and apply for a work permit, your application will be immediately rejected. https://www.germany-visa.org/immigration/working-germany-getting-german-work-permit/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> - Can I convert my Schengen Visa to a work permit visa if I can get a job offer when I'm in Germany with that Schengen Visa?
> - Can I convert my Schengen Visa to a Job seeker visa or any other kind of visa that lets me stay for 6 months or more to find a job in Germany or other Schengen countries when I'm there?

No, you must apply for a **National Visa** (Type D) in the country of your main residence.

As a general rule, the German consulate in the country where you applied for the Schengen Visa (Type C), will be responsible for the issuing of the National Visa.

> [What is the procedure for applying for a work visa?](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/buergerservice/faq/07-arbeitsvisum/606666)
> As a general rule non-EU nationals need a residence title (visa or residence permit) to take up employment in Germany. By law the residence title has to give information whether and to which extent access to the labour market is granted. This information replaces the former work permit. If you intend to commence work in Germany **you have to apply for a visa with the competent German mission abroad *before* entering Germany**. (Only nationals of Australia, Canada, Israel, Japan, New Zealand, South Korea [, United Kingdom] and the United States may apply for the necessary residence title **after** arrival in Germany.)
>
> Details as to which documents have to be presented with your visa application are available on the webpage of the competent German mission abroad or directly from the mission itself.
>
> > [I would like to apply for a visa](https://teheran.diplo.de/ir-de/-/2403868?openAccordionId=item-2403870-1-panel)
> >
> > - The visa office is located at Bukharest Street, 8th St, No.  7, Arian Building, Tehran, Iran.
> > - VISAMETRIC acceptance center is located at Shirazi Building 1st Floor, No 137, Cross 21st Street, Vozara Avenue, 15139, Tehran.

---

**Sources**:

- [Visa for Germany - Federal Foreign Office](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/buergerservice/faq/-/606848)

  - [What is the procedure for applying for a work visa? - Federal Foreign Office](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/buergerservice/faq/07-arbeitsvisum/606666)
  - [Nationale Visa - Auswärtiges Amt - Ich möchte ein Visum beantragen](https://teheran.diplo.de/ir-de/-/2403868?openAccordionId=item-2403870-1-panel) (in German)

    - A Farsi version is available (Top, left hand side of page)
- [§41(1) - Vergünstigung für Angehörige bestimmter Staaten (AufenthV)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__41.html)

  - **Note**: The United Kingdom was added on the 2021-01-01, but in 2024 not all sites listing these countries have been updated.